# Automatically transform XML file using XSD

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

I have objects serialized to XML. In case of software update those serialized objects might become inconsistent to a new software version (e.g. my objects got a new property).

Let's say this is my XML:

```
<Object>
  <Property1>prop1</Property1>
  <Property2>prop2</Property2>
</Object>
```

My new version expexts Objects in the following format:

```
<Object>
  <Property1>...</Property1>
  <Property3>...</Property3>
</Object>
```

In case i have thousands of i don't want to manually remove Property2 and add Property 3.
Is there a way to automatically transform my old XMLs to a new XSD schema?